# Compare each element of a list to the mean of the remainder of the list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, averages

If I have a list

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Is there some way of taking the first element and then comparing it to the average of the other `4` elements? Then to take element `2` and compare it to the average of elements `1, 3, 4, 5`? I can see how to do this with a `For` loop and a procedural style, but I am wondering if an easy functional style solution is possible.

Similar to this:

```
 1 == Mean[{2, 3, 4, 5}]
 2 == Mean[{1, 3, 4, 5}]
 3 == Mean[{1, 2, 4, 5}]
```

P.S. I plan on using a more elaborate comparison, but `==` seemed like an easy one for this example.

Comment: If by "compare" you mean testing whether the values are equal, it'd be useful to notice that if a value is equal to the mean of the rest of the list, then the same value is equal to the mean of the entire list. So you only have to compute the mean once.

Comment: If you are curious, the reason I am doing this is because I am a microscopist doing image alignment with tiny beads.  I want to take the displacement of each bead an see if it falls within some arbitrary threshold compared to all the other beads.  Any bead that drifts outside this threshold should be discarded because it was probably perturbed in some way different than the rest of the beads :).  IE i want to take the displacement of one bead and compare to the average of all the rest of the beads. (for all the beads)

Comment: olliepower, can `lst` have duplicate elements?

Comment: Why not use something simple like `MeanFilter[lst, 2] - lst`? That way you can play with different smoothing filters, too (e.g. `GaussianFilter`, `MedianFilter`)

Comment: Yes, @kglr lst can have duplicate elements

Comment: then  for, say, `lst1 = {1, 1, 1, 1}` you should get `{True, True, True, True}`  and  for `lst2 = {1, 1, 2, 3/2} `  you should get `{False, False, False, False}` right? (If yes, try `F` from the accepted answer with `lst1` and `lst2`)

Comment: @kglr you are correct.  For the second version of F, it fails with `lst1` because it looks like compliment returns and empty set. any suggestions @J42161217 ?  I suppose I will test the other answers as well.  I quite liked how succinct this was.  Thank you at @kglr for catching this!  Will test your solution when i'm done teaching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[subMeans]
subMeans = (Total[#] - #)/(Length[#] - 1) &;
```

**Examples:**

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
subMeans[lst]
```

> {1/3 (b + c + d), 1/3 (a + c + d), 1/3 (a + b + d), 1/3 (a + b + c)}

```
subMeans[{a, b, b, b}]
```

> {b, 1/3 (a + 2 b), 1/3 (a + 2 b), 1/3 (a + 2 b)}

```
MapThread[Equal, {#, subMeans @ #}]& @ lst
```

> {a == 1/3 (b + c + d), b == 1/3 (a + c + d), c == 1/3 (a + b + d), 
>      d == 1/3 (a + b + c)}

```
MapThread[Equal, {#, subMeans @ #}]& @ Range[5]
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

**Update:** For checking equality, there is a simpler way (because $x_i = \frac{\sum_{j \neq i}^{n} x_j}{n-1}$ iff $x_i =\frac{\sum_{j = 1 }^{n} x_j}{n}$):

```
Thread[# == Mean[#]] &@Range[5]
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

Comment: Changed my accepted answer to this one, as this is what I am now using in my implementation.  This method does not fail when elements are repeated in a list.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to choose a specific element use

```
F[x_] := Mean@Complement[lst, {x}]
1 == F[1]
2 == F[2]
3 == F[3]
```

> False
>   False
>   True

**Note**

if you want to choose the first,second,nth element use

```
F[x_] := Mean@Complement[lst, {lst[[x]]}]    
1 == F[1]
2 == F[2]
3 == F[3]
```

> False
>   False
>   True

Comment: This is the one I went with because the implementation is really easy to understand, its clear, and it is short :)

Comment: I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
(Last@# == Mean@Most@# &) /@ (RotateLeft[lst, #] & /@ Range@Length@lst)
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

Ugly version.

```
(First@# - Mean@Last@# == {0} &) /@ (TakeDrop[lst, {#}] & /@ Range@Length@lst)
```

Answer (score 3):

If one takes stock of the fact that for a list of numbers, the iterative procedure described in the *Q* amounts to using the excluded entry along with the average calculated in the previous step, then correcting for the current step exclusion in order to obtain the desired figures makes implementing a functional solution straightforward.

```
crawlingComparison[list_, comp_: Equal] := Module[{e0, rest = Rest[list], len = Length[list]-1},

  e0 = {#[[1]], #[[-1]], comp[#[[1]], #[[-1]]]} &@{First[list], Mean[rest]};

  FoldList[
    With[{ej = #2, mj = #1[[2]] + #1[[1]]/len - #2/len},
      {ej, mj, comp[ej, mj]}] &, e0, rest][[All, -1]]
 ]
```

(irrelevant note: I'm calling it `crawlingComparison` because it feels like the preceding entry crawls up to the calculated mean figure and *forces* it to update itself.)

### An example

using the `list` provided in the *Q*:

```
crawlingComparison[list]
```

> ```
> {False, False, True, False, False}
> ```

### Another example

If the desired comparison operator is different from `Equal` that can be accommodated using the second argument of `crawlingComparison`:

Using as a comparison operator the function `comp = (#1 - #2)^2 <= 1&` (just an arbitrary choice):

```
crawlingComparison[list, comp]
```

> ```
> {False, False, True, False, False}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

TakeList[lst, {{#}, All}] & /@ Range@Length@lst
```

> {{{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{2}, {1, 3, 4, 5}}, {{3}, {1, 2, 4,     5}},
> {{4}, {1, 2, 3, 5}}, {{5}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}}

---

To apply the predicate:

```
TakeList[lst, {{#}, All}] & /@ Range@Length@lst // 
 Map[Equal[First@First@#, Mean@Last@#] &]
```

> {False, False, True, False, False}

Answer (score 2):

```
MapIndexed[{#1,Delete[lst,#2]}&,lst]

(* {
    {1,{2,3,4,5}},
    {2,{1,3,4,5}},
    {3,{1,2,4,5}},
    {4,{1,2,3,5}},
    {5,{1,2,3,4}}} *)
```

To take the `Mean`

```
MapIndexed[{#1,Mean@Delete[lst,#2]}&,lst]

(* {{1,7/2},{2,13/4},{3,3},{4,11/4},{5,5/2}} *)
```

To compare

```
MapIndexed[#1==Mean@Delete[lst,#2]&,lst]

(* {False,False,True,False,False} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

With[{rot = RotateLeft[list, #] & /@ Range[0, Length @ list - 1]},
 KeyValueMap[Equal] @ GroupBy[rot, First -> Rest, First /* Mean]]
```

{False, False, True, False, False}